# What is the difference between an generalised estimating equation and a recurrent neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, comparison, recurrent-neural-networks, linear-regression, statistical-ai

What is the difference between a generalised estimating equation (GEE) model and a recurrent neural network (RNN) model, in terms of what these two models are doing? Apart from the differences in the structure of these two models, where GEE is an extension of generalised linear model (GLM) and RNN is of a neural network structure, it seems to me that these 2 models are doing the same thing?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a reference that describes "generalised estimating equation (GEE)"?

Comment: What do you understand each of these to be doing? An RNN is a general function approximator, which can compute _sample_ level targets from input data, whereas a GEE estimates _population_ level effects.